# Suppose $f(x) \rightarrow M$ as $x \rightarrow a$. Prove that if $f(x) \leq L$ for all $x$ near $a$, then $M \leq L$.

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'm am a student taking a real analysis paper at university. I'm going through some problems on my problem sheet and I've been asked the question above.

I'm still getting a hang on what it means for $x$ to be "near" $a$ but gather, that if $f(a) \leq L$ and $f(a) = M$ then $M \leq L$ is implied.

If anyone can help me understand the mathematical definition of something being "near" something else and some tips on how to carve a rigorous proof of the above. It would be much appreciated!

Thank you for your time!

Comment: In this case, near means that there is an open interval $I$ containing $a$ such that the property holds for all $x \in I$.

Comment: See: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3632091/suppose-that-x-n-rightarrow-x-as-n-rightarrow-infty-prove-from-first-pr?rq=1

Comment: Let $\lim\limits_{x\to a} f(x)=M$ and $\exists\delta:\,\forall x: |x-a|<\delta\Rightarrow f(x)\le L$ and $M>L$. Then observe $\varepsilon$--$\delta$ limit definition and find a contradiction for some $\varepsilon$, say $M-L$ or $\frac{M-L}{2}$. Perhaps you'll need triangle inequality.

Answer (score 3):

Let $\epsilon>0$ be a small number, e.g., $\epsilon=0.01$ (it can be any number). Then, for any such $\epsilon$, you can define an $\epsilon$-neighborhood $U_\epsilon(a)$ of $a$ by

$$U_\epsilon(a)=\{x\in\mathbb R: d(x,a)<\epsilon\}$$

where $d(\cdot,\cdot)$ is some [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)), e.g., $d(x,a)=|x-a|$ (the absolute value of their difference). Then, in this exercise, you know that $f(x)\le M$ for all $x\in U_\epsilon(a)$ and this for every $\epsilon>0$ sufficiently small, i.e., *near $a$*.

Note: the exercise does not specify whether this holds for any $\epsilon<0.01$ or any $\epsilon<0.001$ and this is where you may think that the statement has some ambiguity. But actually you don't need to know the exact threshold, only that for *sufficiently small $\epsilon>0$*, i.e., *near $a$*, you have some desired property.

Comment: +1 And you would generally use this condition as "there exists some $\epsilon$ such that for  $x\in U_{\epsilon}(a)$..."

Answer (score 1):

In fact an even stronger version of this result holds. Suppose $f, g$ are real functions defined on $X \subset \mathbb{R}$, let $a \in X'$ and suppose also that:

$$\lim_{x \to a } f(x) = L < \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = M$$

Then there's a neighbourhood $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ of $a$ in which $f < g$. Indeed, setting $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}(M - L) > 0$, we have $L + \varepsilon = M -\varepsilon$, and by the definition of limits there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that $x \in (a- \delta, a + \delta) \implies |f(x) -  L| < \varepsilon$ and $g(x) \in (M - \varepsilon, M + \varepsilon)$, therefore 
$$f(x) < \frac{L + M}{2} < g(x) \text{ for all }x \in (a - \delta, a + \delta)$$

An immediate corollary of this is that if $f \leq g$ everywhere and:

$$\lim_{x \to a } f(x) = L \text{ and } \lim_{x \to a} g(x) = M $$

then $L \leq M$. Your desired result is then an immediate consequence of this.

Answer (score 1):

Given: $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x)=M$, and in a $\delta$ neighbourhood of $a$, i.e. there is a $\delta >0$ s.t.

$|x-a| \lt \delta$ implies $f(x)\le L.$

Assume $M >L$.

For $|x-a|<\delta$ we have  $f(x)\le L <M.$

Let $n_0 >1/\delta$ (Archimedean principle).

For $n\ge n_0$

$|x_n-a| <1/n \le 1/n_0 <\delta$, i.e. the $x_n$ are near enough and converge to $a$.

Then

$f(x_n) \le L <M$, and

$M=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}f(x_n)\le L<M$, a contradiction.